# Using the address of an object as Map key in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have defined a Map to store some Int value against the nodes of my tree. The Node class is defined as:

```
case class Node(value: Int, var left: Node = null, var right: Node)
```

and the Map

```
private val hMap = new mutable.HashMap[Node, Int]()
```

When I print this Map, I get the following:

```
Map(Node(8,null,null) -> 1, Node(11,null,null) -> 1, Node(2,Node(3,null,null),Node(4,Node(5,null,Node(6,null,null)),null)) -> 4)
```

I was hoping to see the reference to (or the address of) the Node object that I am storing as key in my Map. Is my assumption still valid and the print method is serializing the object while printing. If this is not true, then how can I create a Map of type  (referenceTo(Node) -> some int value).

Comment: So do you want something like an IdentityHashMap?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html
It also has a Scala counterpart.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Printing a case class will print its representation. If you want the map value, make a new Node class that has the same structure

Comment: Add the code you used to create that tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding hashcode and equals to be based on the reference. You can use the scala `eq` operator to match objects based on reference inside the equality check.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val hMap = new  mutable.HashMap[Node,Int]()
    val n1 = Node(1,null,null)
    val n3=new Node(3,null,null)
    val n2=new Node(2,n1,n3)
    hMap.put(n1,1)
    hMap.put(n2,2)
    hMap.put(n3,3)

    hMap foreach( println)

    println(hMap get new Node(1,null,null))

  }

  case class Node(value: Int, var left: Node = null, var right: Node) {
    override def equals(obj: scala.Any): Boolean = {
      if (obj.isInstanceOf[Node]) {
        val tmp = obj.asInstanceOf[Node]
        (tmp.value == this.value)
        // add more conditions for equality
      }else false
    }
    override def hashCode(): Int = {
        this.value
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Sumeet, This is what I was looking for.